# Javascript ternary operator hidden logic

Tags: javascript, ternary, operands

```js
function even_or_odd(number) {
  return number % 2 === 0 ? 'Even' : 'Odd';
}

function even_or_odd(number) {
  return number % 2 ? "Odd" : "Even"
}
```

Why do these two functions return the same result?

How does `return number % 2 ? "Odd" : "Even"` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0` in javascript is a falsy value.

```js
var v = 0;

if(v) {
  console.log("true");
} else {
  console.log("false");
}
```

`number % 2` will return either `0` (which is `falsy`) or `1` (which is `truthy`). So if the `number` is `even` then `number % 2` will return `0` and the condition of the ternary will be `false`, ...